# Operating System's OpenGL

Tags: opengl

is it true if the Operating System only provides OpenGL version 1.0 and if we want to use the newer version, we should install GPU driver or using something like GLAD?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly because the supported OpenGL version has nothing to do with GLAD (which provides OpenGL function headers). The major limiting factor is whether your hardware supports the OpenGL version you are trying to run, then if your OS/driver (which is basically the same thing here) supports that version.

Comment: What operating system are you referring to?

Comment: Windows and Linux

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is almost true.

**Windows**

In Windows, the operating system includes a built-in software renderer for OpenGL, typically referred to as the opengl32.dll library, which supports only OpenGL 1.0 functionality. However, this legacy driver is almost never used for modern graphics applications because it lacks hardware acceleration and does not provide access to advanced OpenGL features.

When you install graphics drivers from manufacturers like NVIDIA, AMD, or Intel, they replace this default software renderer with their own hardware-accelerated OpenGL drivers. These manufacturer-specific drivers intercept and handle OpenGL API calls, enabling applications to leverage the full range of OpenGL features and capabilities offered by the underlying GPU hardware.

OpenGL functionality introduced after version 1.0 is typically referred to as extensions. These extensions are additional features and capabilities that applications can access through the OpenGL API. To manage and utilize these extensions, developers often turn to libraries like the OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library (GLEW). GLEW simplifies the process of querying and enabling extensions, making it easier for applications to tap into advanced OpenGL features while ensuring compatibility across various GPU and driver configurations.

**Linux**

In Linux, OpenGL support is versatile and depends on various factors. Most Linux distributions come with Mesa 3D, an open-source graphics library that provides OpenGL functionality. The OpenGL version offered by Mesa can vary, but it often includes support for a reasonable range of OpenGL features. However, users looking for better performance and access to the latest OpenGL capabilities can opt to install proprietary GPU drivers from manufacturers such as NVIDIA and AMD. These proprietary drivers offer enhanced support for newer OpenGL versions and extensions, ensuring that Linux users can harness the full power of their GPUs for graphics-intensive applications. To manage and leverage OpenGL extensions effectively on Linux, developers can still turn to libraries like the OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library (GLEW), which simplifies the process of working with advanced OpenGL features, thereby ensuring compatibility across different Linux distributions and GPU configurations